# how to show my associate in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have used

```
f.association :estado, collection:@estados, value_method: :id, label_method: :nome, required: true, prompt: "Please Select"
```

to save my association and now when go to "index"  show me it

> Estado:0x00007f09fdcc99e0>

is my first post sorry anything.

I'm using rails 5.1 if it helps

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Luiz Henrique Are you trying to use `select_tag`?

Comment: no, I made an association and at the time of viewing it appears this code(Estado:0x00007f09fdcc99e0>)

Comment: @LuizHenrique so far as i think you are trying to make is select tag `prompt: "Please Select"`

Comment: I put a picture of the problem

Comment: Please post the code from html file and controller action as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estado is a model, and a table in your database. Maybe associated to an address. Use:

```
@address.estado.name #assuming address is the instance variable.
```